# Geddy Save User

Tags: javascript, node.js, geddy

I am currently involved helping out on a project which involves using the Geddy js framework, which it is my first time using. I am currently trying to fix the create method inside a model for users. Here is the code below:

```
this.create = function (req, resp, params) {
    var self = this
      , user = geddy.model.User.create(params);

    //need to ensure that the user agrees with the terms and conditions.

    // Non-blocking uniqueness checks are hard
    geddy.model.User.first({username: user.username}, function(err, data) {
      if (data) {
        params.errors = {
          username: 'This username is already in use.'
        };
        //self.transfer('add');
      }
      else {
        if (user.isValid()) {
          user.password = cryptPass(user.password);
          user.suburb = "";
          user.state = "";
          user.postcode = "";
        }
        user.save(function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            params.errors = err;
            self.transfer('add');
          }
          else {
              // setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
              var mailOptions = {
                  from: "App ✔ <hello@app.com>", // sender address
                  to: user.email, // list of receivers
                  subject: user.username + " Thank you for Signing Up ✔", // Subject line
                  text: "Please log in and start shopping! ✔", // plaintext body
                  html: "<b>Please log in and start shopping!✔</b>" // html body
              }

              smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
                  if(error){
                      console.log(error);
                  }else{
                      console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
                  }

                  // if you don't want to use this transport object anymore, uncomment following line
                  smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
              });
            self.redirect({controller: self.name});
          }
        });
      }
    });
};
```

If you look in the code there is apparently a check to see if the so-called user is valid like so: `if (user.isValid()) {
     user.password = cryptPass(user.password);
     user.suburb = "";
     user.state = "";
     user.postcode = "";
}`

The proceeds on to 'save' regardless whether or not the user is valid. I'm thinking why is the code this way? It sounds nonsensical. I asked the original developer who was on the project about it and he said the model was apparently generated when he created the project.

So in bit of a confused state, if anyone can tell me why the save method is outside the if statement in the first place? Is it something the original creators of Geddy intended? or is really nonsensical and I should change it?

Thanks.

Comment: What does `user.isValid` do? It could be setting a property that `user.save` evaluates before returning an error. Or it could be by design that it always saves. Sure, seems strange, but does it work as expected for valid and invalid users?

Comment: apparently it is Geddy's method of validating models and their properties

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with geddy, but it does seem like one would want to return an error if the user is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Geddy's `save()` call will error out if the data is invalid (unless force flag is set, which it isn't). It uses the same `isValid()` call actually. So, looks like what you have here is just someone's way to have a single error handler for all the error cases.

For `user.password` being set with crypted data only if the data looks valid, I'm guessing this is simply to make 'must be set' type of validation to work. Chances are that even with an empty password, the crypted string would be otherwise counted as set.